# Identify file format from header?

Tags: puzzle, file-format

I got some files , which has header,

```
{AD08E961-F492-11d1-B0EA-00AA00683350}2.00:en_US:45015:021
```

Can you please help me in finding out, from which software it is created.

Only information I have is, This file is created around 2000-2003.

I want to parse these files and want to extract some data.

Thanks,
 Sunny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files (NAO, NLO) came with SkillSoft's courses. I think it's encrypted to protect the content. You need to use SkillSoft/NetG player to read it.

Comment: Thanks ZZ Coder, Just for curiosity, I want to know that is it possible to know that by which encryption file is protected without asking netg guys.

Comment: Is there some brute-force way to crack protection?

Comment: I have no idea how to crack it. I don't think you need brute-force though if you have the course on your computer. The key must be in the  code or over the wire. If the course is SCORM compatible, you might want try to import it into DOKEOS, which is open-source.

Answer (score 1):

Do they have the extension NLO? A Googling of the GUID returns just one source, which possibly leads back to something called NetG Skill Builder which is training software.

Comment: Thanks, It has an extension NLO. Can you tell me how to read that file?

Comment: I think you might have to contact these guys : http://www.netg.com . Problem is, as far as I can tell they don't sell NetG Skill Builder anymore but mostly do online training over the web.